# What are the default placement options for a floating figure in Latex?

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

The document [Using Imported Graphics in L A TEX and pdfL A TEX](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) talks about the different ways to affect where a floating figure is placed `[htbp]`. But these arguments are optional ...

So how is the float placed if I don't enter any options? Is not entering any options equal to `[htbp]` or some other combination of placement demands? If so which?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The one thing about floats that Frank's opus does _not_ answer is the question asked here.

Comment: Just a small addition. They are optional but also restrictive. Eg if you only put [bp] then you override the default and latex is only allowed to put it in bottom or new page. Took me ages to understand the difference that it's not a preference but requirement :)

Comment: @Trefex yes which is why using `[h]` is such a bad idea, as it means not top, not bottom and not on a float page, which doesn't give latex many options....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle exactly, I always use [!htb] which fits my needs for most of the cases.

Comment: @Trefex that's almost as bad:-) It's logically dubious to have a default that you don't want and then over-ride the default on every instance of a float. Better to set the defaults that you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that certainly makes more sense. However, sometimes one simply doesn't know where to look, or in my case, I was too lazy until now to think about it... :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is set in the class per float type

`article.cls` defines

```
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
```

so for figures and tables the default is `[tbp]`

---

In two column mode, where `figure*` and `table*` span the columns this default is not used, and latex defines

```
\def\@dbflt#1{\@ifnextchar[{\@xdblfloat{#1}}{\@xdblfloat{#1}[tp]}}
```

so the default is `tp` you could redefine that to be `p` but simpler if you just wanted `p` would be to declare

```
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{0}
```

to ban spanning top floats.

Comment: report.cls contains the same lines indicating `tbp` placement

Comment: @spinup yes, article report and book are all produced from the same source file (classes.dtx)

Comment: What about `figure*` default position? The above solution does not work for `figure*`, at least when used, as supposed, in a two column document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544563/28685

Comment: @mmj sorry wrong comment initially, latex does `\def\@dbflt#1{\@ifnextchar[{\@xdblfloat{#1}}{\@xdblfloat{#1}[tp]}}`   so it's always `tp` but you could redefine that command to be just `p`