# Table not displaying in desired location

Tags: tables, formatting

I am writing a lab report and I want to display the a table underneath my Results section. This is my code:

[image: code]

However, the result looks like this:

[image: output]

Why is this the case? Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you would post code as *code*, using text instead of an image.

Comment: What document class are you using? As you haven't defined where the float can go it'll go to the default defined by the document class. [This might help.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172782/what-are-the-default-placement-options-for-a-floating-figure-in-latex)

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

Comment: Then as you can see from the link I posted the default positions are [tbp] which makes sense as your table is at the top of the page. If you don't want it to float then you don't need to use a floating environment (table). If you do then tell it where the float can be placed.

Comment: A little tip about the table layout: load the package `booktabs` and replace your `\hline` with `booktab`'s `\toprule`. The spacing is far better.

Comment: the tabular would go where you place it in the source. The _only_ reason to wrap that in a table environment is to allow latex to move it table is a floating environment, designed to allow tables to move to avoid bad page breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you haven't specified where the float can actually go. This means that it will go to the default position defined by the document class. As you're using the article class that means the default is `[tbp]`.

Your table appears to be at the top of the page. So you can either tell it to go somewhere else with, for example, `h` or arguably if you don't want it to float then don't use the table environment altogether.

You can use the `\captionof` command as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31737/caption-on-tabular-environment) to keep your caption if you want to remove the table environment.