# How to move Figures up from the end?

Tags: appendices, appendix

I am trying to use a Latex template which for whatever reason is always putting figures at the end even though I have one section (Appendix) written after the command to input figures. Any idea how to move the figures before the last section ? There are a lot of other files part of the template package that I don't understand. I am trying to compile this on Overleaf.

Here is the sequence of commands

```
\makeaffiliation

\input{aktomo_figs}

\clearpage

\section{Appendix A1 blah blah blah}

Text in that section

\end{document}
```

The file `aktomo_figs.tex` has figures in the following format

```
%\clearpage\pagebreak
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=16cm]{figures/fig1.jpg}
\caption[Figure description here]
{
Description of the figure blah blah blah
\label{fig:figg1}
}
\end{figure}
```

When I compile this Overleaf always plots the figures at the end even though there is supposed to be a section after that. Any idea how to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The placement of figures depends on many factors, among them document class, settings in the preamble, text width, and more. So please provide a complete small document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that illustrates your problem. Otherwise the people here will not be able to give advice.

Comment: a figure will never go past `\clearpage` (unless you use a package like `endfloat` that always moves all figures to the end as required by some journal submission formats.

Comment: wow you are absolutely right @DavidCarlisle. unfortunately removing `endfloat` screws up all the figures, the captions extend all the way to the edge of the page. i just submitted the paper as it was, hopefully the journal would not mind the Appendix being before the figures.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172782/what-are-the-default-placement-options-for-a-floating-figure-in-latex ... gives a hint how to check standard float priority for document class

Comment: If endfloat is part of a publisher's document class or template, don't mess with it.  They **want** the figures at the end.